# SQL cannot identify datatype SERIAL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

Thanks in advance,
I do not get why SERIAL is not recognized as a data type.
the code is really simple tho.
I also have a question:
Since SERIAL is not a true type, do I have to define it somewhere?

```
CREATE TABLE flights (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    origin VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    destination VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    duration INTEGER NOT NULL,
);
```

[image]

Comment: Because SQL Server [does not have that type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - it's a PostgreSQL specific type.

Comment: aah, are there much difference between postgreSQL and SQL?

Comment: PostgreSQL uses SQL as it's query language (just like every relational database). But yes there are differences between PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL Server (or any other database product).

Comment: @AleksandreBregadze database products are **very** different from each other. No database offers more than basic compliance with the SQL standard. All databases use their own extensions

Comment: `SERIAL` is an autoincrementing int. You can create the same with `int IDENTITY(1,1)`. To get a long, use `bigint IDENTITY(1,1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table definition should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE flights (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    origin VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    destination VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    duration INTEGER NOT NULL,
);
```

As mentioned in the comments, `serial` comes from Postgres.  Even in that database, its use is now obsolete, replaced by `generated always as identity`.

I don't know what the lengths of `origin` and `destination` are.  But . . . in SQL Server, *never* use `char()` or related types without a length.  The default length varies by context and bugs in this area are very hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to explore a little bit more SQL Server documentation on data types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

SERIAL as in PostgreSQL translates to `INT IDENTITY` on SQL Server.

That said, the second column, `origin`, is declared as a VARCHAR with no length. I'm not sure if it will default to 1 or 30 positions. Anyway, I shall advise against a VARCHAR with no explicit length...